# Discord.py Lyrics command issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have made this lyrics search command and it works well. The problem is most of the lyrics that are returned are over 2000 characters. How can I make a new embed for this and continue the lyrics?

```py
@bot.command()
    async def lyrics(ctx , * , q):
      
      genius = Genius('abcxyz')
      song = genius.search_song(q)
      em = discord.Embed(title = 'Here is the result -' , description = song.lyrics)
      #await ctx.send(song.lyrics)
      await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Comment: Do you want a pagination sort of thing?

Comment: yes , that can be good

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

`lyrics = "*Your Lyrics*"`

`part1 = lyrics[1999]`

`and send part1, and to get part2`

`part2 = lyrics[:lyrics-part1] # or something like that`